# Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build\flutter_assets"

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, sdk, runtime-error

I'm working on flutter to develop a "map-navigation app". I'm new to it. It showed "some of the dependencies are outdated" so I update the packages and pub files, after that the application is not running on any of the platform (i.e. Desktop, Web, android and ios). It shows the following given error.

Also tried manually deleting the build folder from the project and then executing the app, still facing the same error.

Manually deleting the build folder, applying `flutter clean` command then running the app still shows the error below:

[image]

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build\flutter_assets". 
The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed 
in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
```

[image: Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build\flutter_assets"]

I want to execute this application on web or android.
Want to provide flutter tool the access to file or directory.

Comment: try the following, move your project to c:\users\public\   and then open cmd into that folder, run flutter clean command and then open this project and try to run. see if it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably because it is not a good idea to have a space in the path to a flutter project ie. 'HP PC' would be better named with an underscore instead of the space character.

The flutter documentation warns you of this here https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows

Comment: Yes, it's the main cause. Thank you

Comment: Ok good. You probably should upvote one or both of us that you think helped you. That encourages people to help you next time, and what you will want when you help someone. That's what drives SO.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who faces this issue in future, as mentioned by @GrahamD this issue is because of space in the path. In this case it's `HP PC` that should be `HP_PC` or `HPPC` or any valid string. Here are few ways you can troubleshoot this issue.

- Rename the user account. Examples: `mypc`, `my_pc`, `MyPc`, myPC,
  etc.
- Change the working directory to the path that doesn't contain
  space/s. Example: C:\Users\Public\ etc.
- Create a new user with a name having no space/s.

After moving your directory, run `flutter clean` command and then run your project again. It should work now.

Note: You may need to install software if you create a new user account.

Comment: In my case, I don't have any space in between but I have upper case, so I move my project to another drive (D: drive) with the proper name (lower and underscore). Maybe it shows an error because of the C: drive as @thobani said, it restricts some activity.

Answer (score 1):

One of the issues could be that the project is running from C: drive, if possible you can move the project to a different drive. C: drive usually has a lot of restrictions.

Comment: it works for me after changing to D: drive from C: drive. Yeayyyy

Answer (score 0):

This was my error when try to debug the Flutter app on my Android smartphone>:

```
Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\Jean-Pierre\Development\Flutter\audio_learn\build\app\outputs\apk\debug' 
Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process 
has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
```

The problem could only be solved by restarting Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's `folder/build/` and delete `flutter_assets`.
That is it!

Answer (score 0):

For me it is because my I had not updated the `.gitIgnore` to avoid `build` folder so my git tool had included it so didn't allow to delete